# What were the source documents of the PTS Sutta Pitaka?

Tags: pali-canon, history

The Pali Text Society published editions of the Pali Tipitaka, starting in about 1890.

I assume it was copied (transcribed) from one or more written sources, not from memory, is that so?

From what written documents/sources did the editor[s] of the PTS edition get the text? Were they manuscripts, or printed? And I'm guessing the PTS transcribed the text to Roman script?

Where (in which countries and/or by whom) were those source materials copied? Was it from one source or several?

Would you happen to know whether the source documents still exist today?

[This answer](https://discourse.suttacentral.net/t/list-of-tipitaka-versions-differences/6278/2) says that different editions are more or less the same in every country ...

> With the Pali editions, we inherit a complex manuscript tradition. In each country there are multiple different editions, both modern printed editions and older manuscripts. The ones we have ended up using are more or less random. The problem is that despite the many variations, the reality is that it is a huge amount of work to gather and collate them, and the end result is, “Yep, apart from these few instances, it’s pretty much the same as all the others.”

... still I'm wondering specifically where the text of the PTS edition came from (and where the work was done).

Comment: Do you already know the site of some EBT-friends (and Pali-translators) https://discourse.suttacentral.net/ You might get some authoritative answer there. If you don't have an account there (or don't want to have one) I could ask for you.

Comment: I asked three questions there last year.

Comment: Related: [How was the Buddha Jayanti edition of the Tripitaka derived?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/2015/254)

Comment: Related: [List of tipitaka versions’ differences](https://discourse.suttacentral.net/t/list-of-tipitaka-versions-differences/6278) (on SuttaCentral)

Comment: Wow, the links give well exposed material. Hope you'll get what you're looking for!

Comment: Also there's [a letter here](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.277460/2015.277460.1425_W_O_djvu.txt) from Mrs. Rhys Davis which begins, `When, some sixty-five years ago, my husband retired from` which gives some clues about "how" and some explanation of motive, "why".

Comment: oh, If I should once happen to lie in bed with broken leg or so, I'd try to re-format that complete text... It seems it would be a very good piece of history to have this as a book or as fluent electronic text!

Comment: @GottfriedHelms It's great, isn't it -- written with a wife's loving hindsight, and appreciation (e.g. to the monk who first taught her husband) and as a public plea to others for help with continuing the work.

Comment: Well said, Chris. And blessed is someone who finds karuna...

Answer (score 1):

Sources Consulted for the PTS Pali Nikāya Texts

**Dīgha Nikāya**

Edited by
Vol. 1, 1890: T.W. Rhys Davids and J.E. Carpenter
Vol. 2, 1903: T.W. Rhys Davids and J.E. Carpenter
Vol. 3, 1911: J.E. Carpenter

Ph = M = B - the Phayre MS. of the India Office Library (Burm. ch)
B<sup>m</sup> Burmese ms, royal Mandalay Collection, India Office, No. 40
B<sup>r</sup> Printed Burmese text, Rangoon
S<sup>m</sup> A ms in Sinhalese characters in the possession of Professor Rhys Davids
S<sup>c</sup> Sinhalese manuscript belonging to J.E. Carpenter
S<sup>d</sup> Sinhalese ms. belonging to T.W. Rhys Davids
S<sup>t</sup> Sinhalese ms, Turnour Collection, India Office
Si = K  Printed Siamese text, King of Siam's edition 1893 (Siamese ch)
RhD<sup>t</sup> Rhys Davids' trnscript

**Majjhima Nikāya**

Edited by
Vol. 1, 1888, V. Trenckner
Vol. 2, 1896, R. Chalmers
Vol. 3, 1899, R. Chalmers

A = - S<sup>k</sup> the Copenhagen MS. No. VI (Singh. ch)
Ph = M = B - the Phayre MS. of the India Office Library (Burm. ch)
S<sup>t</sup> Sinhalese ms, Turnour Collection, India Office
B<sup>m</sup> Burmese ms, royal Mandalay Collection, India Office, No. 40
Si = K  Printed Siamese text, King of Siam's edition 1893 (Siamese ch)

**Anguttara Nikāya**

Edited by
Vol. 1, 1885, R. Morris, 2nd Ed.: A.K. Wrder
Vol. 2, 1888, R. Morris
Vol. 3, 1897, E. Hardy
Vol. 4, 1899, E. Hardy
Vol. 5, 1900, E. Hardy

T = S<sup>t</sup> Sinhalese ms, Turnour Collection, India Office
Ba No. 2276 (in Sinhalese) of the Oriental Mss. in the Library of the British Museum
Bb No. 2412 (in Sinhalese ch)  of the Oriental Mss. in the Library of the British Museum
Ph = M = B - the Phayre MS. of the India Office Library (Burm. ch)
B<sup>m</sup> #122, #123 Burmese ms, royal Mandalay Collection, India Office, No. 40
S.M. (Sinhalese ch) Morris collection
B.K. Burmese texts
M. #s 125, 130 of the Mandalay collection (Burmese ch), India Office Lib.
M<sub>6</sub> Morris Ms. (Sinhalese ch)
M<sub>7</sub> Morris Ms. (Sinhalese ch)
M <sub>8</sub> Morris Ms. (Burmese)
S = Si = K  Printed Siamese text, King of Siam's edition 1893 (Siamese ch)

2nd Ed:
K<sup>e</sup> Siamese editionof the text
C<sup>e</sup> Sinhalese edition of the text
ChS Chaṭṭha Sangīti Piṭakaɱ

**Saɱyutta Nikāya**

Edited by
Vol. 1, 1884, M.L. Feer
Vol. 2, 1888, M.L. Feer
Vol. 3, 1890, M.L. Feer
Vol. 4, 1898, M.L. Feer
Vol. 5, 1890, M.L. Feer

B (Burmese ch) ms of the Bibliotheque nationale in Paris
S<sup>1</sup> Copenhagen ms
S<sup>2</sup> British Museum ms
S<sup>3</sup> Morris ms

Composed as an appendix to the article: On the Importance of the Pali Text Society Translations at

http://buddhadust.net/dhammatalk/dhammatalk_forum/give_ear/ge_015.importance_pts.htm

Answer (score -2):

The Pali PTS Tripitaka was written in Sri Lanka. How it was written is explained here. -> https://qr.ae/TW8x2e

Comment: That explains it was oral tradition until 76 BC, and written after that: but not exactly what the source material was for the PTS editions. They were published starting in about 1890 -- was that from memory (I'm guessing not), from manuscripts (perhaps, but from where or from whom), or from an earlier printed edition?

Comment: So "oral tradition" means the monks recite the Sutta daily in order to retain the Sutta in memory. The 3 baskets were looked after by groups of monks.  Each group would ensure its not forgotten.

Comment: Yes that's what "oral tradition" means. But i'm not asking about the first few hundred years, this question is about the late 19th century, 130 years ago -- from what source[s] did the editor[s] of the PTS edition collect the Pali text for the *suttapiṭaka* which they published?

Comment: The Tipitaka was written in Ola leaf and that is the original source. Almost 95% of the sources would be from Sri Lanka since that was where Buddha lived and his Dhamma existed and the Dhamma councils were conducted. British officers George Turner and Hugh Nevill who worked for the British civil service has taken it from Sri Lanka. its all documented and catalogued. The rest presumably from other countries.

Comment: Having a good Q&A-site means to find answers which adress the questions. It is a really clear formulated question, no place for misunderstanding... (downvote)